# How to create a new sheet in an existing xlsx file using xlsx/sheetjs package in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx, sheetjs

How to **create/ add a new sheet** file in an already existing xlsx file using the **xlsx package by sheetjs** in Node js?

This is my code by far, for an existing "todo-list.xlsx" file.

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
workBook = xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx", {cellDates:true});
```

I would like to do something like this (this is done by using the Excel JS package):

```
const sheet = workbookStream.addSheet('sheet1');
```

... but using the xlsx package.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example of adding a new worksheet to an existing workbook In the official documentation:

```js
var ws_name = "SheetJS";
 
/* make worksheet */
var ws_data = [
  [ "S", "h", "e", "e", "t", "J", "S" ],
  [  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ,  5 ]
];
var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
 
/* Add the worksheet to the workbook */
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, ws_name);
```

See [Working with the Workbook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#modifying-workbook-structure)

Comment: "Working with the Workbook" link should probably be updated to https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#modifying-workbook-structure